# Java :: Triangle Problem

Tags: java

We have triangle made of blocks. The topmost row has 1 block, the next row down has 2 blocks, the next row has 3 blocks, and so on. Compute the total number of blocks in such a triangle with the given number of rows.

```
 triangle(0) => 0     
 triangle(1) => 1     
 triangle(2) => 3
```

The function signature is      `public int triangle(int rows) { }`

I'm unable to proceed with this problem and struggling to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is computing triangular numbers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

```
public int triangle(int rows) {
  return rows * (rows + 1) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Figure out how to solve the program on paper.  (That is your algorithm)
2. Then translate that to code.

Looks like you are trying to do step 2 without doing step 1 first. That will alway make you struggle with what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

You want to calculate the sum of N, N-1, ... to 1.  This is the same as `N * (N + 1) / 2`

```
public int triangle(int rows) { return rows * (rows + 1) / 2; }
```

Comment: @amal, If it was homework, I would expect he was supposed to solve this using recursion and he won't get marks for this answer.  But he didn't say it was homework or that he had to use recursion, so I am giving him this solution instead. ;)

Comment: @amal, I agree, which is why I gave a solution he can't use unless its not homework. ;)